# Remove leading and trailing zeros from string that contains a numeric value using php

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to trim the leading and trailing zeros from a string that contains a numeric value used to represent a percentage.

I wrote this ugly block of code that combines rtrim(), ltrim() with a preg_replace():

```
rtrim(ltrim(preg_replace("/\d*\.(0(?![0$])|[1-9])*\K0+$/", "", $value),"0"), ".")
```

But it doesn't seem to work since if I enter 0010.003000 the output is 10.003000 instead of the desired 10.003

Is there a way to make a regex read right to left in Php (delete zeros from the right until you find a zero or a [1-9])? Or is there a way to improve my regex to accomplish my goal?

Important note:
For some arguable reason I can't do a simple cast to float and simply enjoy the time saved playing videogames.

To better explain my strange question here are some samples with expected behaviors:
01.00    => 1 ,
100      => 100 ,
002.0050 => 2.005 ,
0.005    => .005

Comment: Why don't you simply use `floatval()`? If you need to keep it as a string, you could use `$floatString = "" . floatval($oldString);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/^0+|\..+?\K0+$/g
```

This either matches one or more `0`s at the start-of-string `^0+`, or it matches one or more `0`s at the end-of-string `0+$`.

In PHP:

```
preg_replace_all("/^0+|\..+?\K0+$/", "", $value)
```

**NOTE:** I would recommend using the non regular expression solutions because they are more suitable for this simple situation. Nevertheless I posted this because you asked for a regular expression.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iK2nB9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But unfortunately this solution doesn't seem to work if I enter "100" that gets trimmed into "1"

Comment: @MarcoMatarazzi I have modified my regular expression to solve this issue.

Comment: I checked out your solution but it doesn't seem to work (not even on the demo site) :(

Comment: @MarcoMatarazzi Really sorry for this, I have fixed the regex and the demo. I am really tired today I guess I should go to sleep after this :)

Comment: Please provide a link to the php documentation for `preg_replace_all()` ...I want to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **cast** your string to `float`:

```
$s = '0010.003000';
echo (float) $s;
//=> 10.003
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But (as specified in the question) I can't cast to float, that's why the question is not easy for me :)

Comment: I find it pretty strange that you want to use regex for this task which should be ideally be done using the way I have shown here.

Comment: I agree with you and your solution will work for everyone else that doesn't have my crazy "no cast" condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [floatval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) instead of regex:

```
<?php
$str = "0010.003000";
print floatval($str);
```

Output: `10.003`

Answer (score 0):

What would you say about such regex?

<strike>echo preg_replace("/((^0+)|(0+$))/", "", $value);</strike>

Ok, now I understand the problem ;) Try this:

```
echo preg_replace("/^0*([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*[1-9]))?0*$/", "$1", $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your strange question, I added support for `0.000` that returns `0`:

```
$nbr = preg_replace('/^(0)+\.?0*$|^0+|\.0*$|\.\d+?\K0+$/', '$1', $nbr);
```